# Can't locate Digest/MD5.pm directadmin

Tags: perl, directadmin

I am trying to make backup in directadmin but it shows this error, perl is installed and updated

```
Can't locate Digest/MD5.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /tmp/.perl-ppk-  BP6PxZ/lib .
perl5 .) at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/lib/Cpanel/Pkgacct/Archive/Writer.pm line 12
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/lib/Cpanel/Pkgacct/
Compilation failed in require at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/lib/Cpanel/Pkgacct/Arch
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/lib/Cpanel/Pkgacct/
Compilation failed in require at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/scripts/main.pl line 29
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp/.perl-ppk-BP6PxZ/scripts/main.pl lin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the Digest::MD5 perl module.  Using CPAN is the easiest way.

From your terminal (SSH):

```
cpan

install Digest::MD5
```

Answer (score 41):

If you are running on centos/redhat you can install it with yum :

```
yum install perl-Digest-MD5 -y
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the previous answers. With neither root access nor `cpan`, the instructions in [`meta::cpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5) work like a charm:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Digest::MD5
```

Answer (score 0):

If using conda:

```
conda install perl-digest-md5
```

Comment: my conda can't find perl-digest-md5.     'conda install -c bioconda perl-digest-md5'     works for me.